# How can I pin Uplay games to my start menu?

Tags: windows, start-menu, gaming

I was wondering if there's a way to pin Uplay games to my start menu. I am using Windows 10. There's an app called Steam Tile to pin Steam games to start menu and I wish there was an app like that for Uplay. Is there a way to pin Uplay games to the start menu??

Comment: Create a shortcut to the executable then pin the shortcut.

Comment: will it work on windows 10?

Comment: Why wouldn’t it work on Windows 10?